# How do I run a SSRS report from C# using a C#-produced dataset and export a PDF file?

Tags: c#, reporting-services, .net-4.0, ssrs-2008, pdf-generation

I am looking at using SSRS for some reporting.

- I want to have a C# console program that runs the SSRS report.
- The C# program will save an exported PDF file locally.
- The C# program will run locally.
- The SSRS report is on another computer on the same domain.  All users can access this via a UNC path.
- The C# program will run some calculations on some raw database data, and the results will be the dataset that the SSRS report uses for its charts and tables.

I am having trouble figuring out how to set up a process to do this.  What's the best way to access the report from a C# program?  Using the full UNC path, using a service reference to the ReportService2010.asmx file, using a web reference to the ReportService2010.asmx file, or something else?  How can I provide the SSRS report with a dataset to use for its charts and tables?  How do I programmatically export a PDF file?

As you can tell, I'm very new to SSRS.  The tutorials I've found online either go into too much depth, or not enough.

Answer (score 1):

You need to either pull the report into your application in a reportviewer control in order to supply it with your dataset directly, or your C# program is going to need to insert the data into a database for the SSRS server to process it.

Fortunately, that's the hard part.  Since the report is hosted on another server, you can *easily* access it directly, rendered in the PDF format you desire.  Access the report via the ReportServer endpoint url (by default it'll be SSRSServerURL/ReportServer), and supply it with any necessary parameters, and the appropriate commands to render (&rs:Command=Render&rs:Format=PDF).  For example:

```
http://SSRSNode001/ReportServer/Pages/ReportViewer.aspx?%2fSAMPLEFOLDER%2fSUBFOLDER%2fMYREPORT&PARAM1=123&PARAM2=321&rs:Command=Render&rs:Format=PDF
```

If you end up using a local reportviewer control, you should still be able to have the rendered produce a PDF output.